# Java outputting spaces for an int

Tags: java, string

Write a method in the class named drawOnePoint with int parameters for x and y. This 
method should draw one line in the graph above. Here’s an example: drawOnePoint(3, 
19) should write the following line to the Terminal Window (equivalent to the line for 
y=19 in the graph shown above):

19 |   *

So basically I don't really know how to take the integer 3 and make it into the amount of spaces after the "|" and then print the asterisk afterwards.

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question but I really can't figure it out.

This is what I have so far:

```
public String drawOnePoint(int xCord, int yCord)
{
            System.out.print(yCord + "|" + 
}
```

Comment: what do you want? can you graph?

Comment: i want to know how to print out a space for the number xCord

so if they give me 3 for the xCord how would i convert that to the number of spaces between the | and the asterisk

Answer (score 0):

Do a loop repetition for as much as you need to print the space, and print it

Comment: but how would i tell it to stop and print the asterisks once it's done?

Comment: something like `for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSpaces; i++){System.out.print(" ");} System.out.print("*");`

Comment: You tell the loop to stop by putting a limiting condition. Eg if you want to loop X time, you can do `for(int i=0; i<X; i++) { /* do something*/ }`. To put an asterisk at the end just simply print it

Comment: say i wanted to return "19 |   *" as a single variable string. How would i write that?

Comment: Concatenate the string. `String s = "hello" + " world";` gives you `"hello world"`. Please read the String / StringBuffer manual

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-z.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

The repeat function is what you're looking for.

Comment: His instructor likely wouldn't be happy with that.

Comment: I'd bet dollars against donuts this is a homework question for an "intro to programming" course, where the use of third-party libraries tends to be frowned upon.

Comment: Kinda sounds like. First I thought you knew this guy, then after looking at your profile I understood your point. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use Apache Commons:

Stringutils.padLeft(yourStr,' ',3)+"*":

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29